# Only original thread that created a view can touch its view when using addView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, dynamically-generated

I have a piece of code where I am generating a checklist according to what is in an array. The ScrollView is a parent layout to allow the list to be scrolled when it is long and there is a LinearLayout inside the ScrollView to allow the checkbox to be created dynamically.

My XML code is:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ss_checklist_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_checklist_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My Java code is:

```
    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    assetID = jsonO.getString("AssetID");
                    assetName = jsonO.getString("AssetName");

                    // Create the checkbox dynamically with the asset name and ID of the response
                    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
                    checkbox.setId(Integer.parseInt(assetID));
                    checkbox.setTextSize(30);
                    checkbox.setScaleX(checkboxScale);
                    checkbox.setScaleY(checkboxScale);
                    checkbox.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#606060"));
                    checkbox.setText(assetName);

                    final String index = assetID;
                    checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            submitAsset(index);
                        }
                    });
                    checkList_layout.addView(checkbox);
                }

                buttonFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonGenerate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
```

Everything is working as it should. However, the error comes out when the created checkbox is being added into the layout. This piece of code was tested before and it was working. I've looked on other threads, some stating that I have to run the code on a UI thread instead and some suggest to input a layoutparams which did not work.

Comment: The error message says it all: you need to update (or in this case, add) the view on the UI thread. Read the [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) guide to have a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: I should be using runOnUiThread?

Comment: When i tried wrapping the code with runOnUiThread, I get an error stating that checkbox could not be used in runOnUiThread

Comment: how are you executing the java code? Is it being called from the user interface, or from a thread that you created

Comment: its from a java class. This java class is created when the activity was created.

Comment: The checkbox variable needs to be final (or if you were using Java 8, it would be good as is, because it's _effectively final_) to be available inside the `Runnable` that you pass to `runOnUiThread(...)`.

Comment: would it be correct to be     final Checkbox checkbox = new CheckBox(this) ?

Comment: I would rather wrap the whole checkbox creation code in the Runnable. Just declare  assetID and assetName final within the loop. But really looking at your code, I cannot understand why you have this whole part running on the UI thread. You should just use an AsyncTask, download the json on the background, and do the rest on the UI thread.

Comment: would you be able to provide a small code for it? or a link for the AsyncTask. Sorry I am still learning on Android.